# Get substring at end of string that has no lowercase letters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, substring

I have strings like:

```
[POS Purchase]
POS Signature Purchase International  SKYPE COMMUNICATIO, LUXEMBOURG, LUX
```

or:

```
ATM Cash Withdrawal. Surcharge: -3.0  BNEAIR INT DP LSL4 2, BNE AIRPORT, AUS
```

And I want to get the end of the string that has any character but lowercase letters. For the two examples above, the answer should be:

```
SKYPE COMMUNICATIO, LUXEMBOURG, LUX
```

and

```
BNEAIR INT DP LSL4 2, BNE AIRPORT, AUS
```

How can I achieve this with a regular expression?

Comment: Your requirements don't quite match your examples: "any character but lowercase letters" includes whitespace, punctuation, numbers etc. That's not quite what your examples show, e.g. the second one would have `: -3.0  ` at the start if that was your exact requirement.

Comment: Yes. What I really want is just the part starting with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your need the following regex is what you are looking for :

```
[^a-z]+$
```

The negated character class `[^a-z]+` will match any combination of none lower case characters and the anchor `$` will make that regex engine match the end of the string.

But note that this will match `-3.0` in your second example.And if you want to get ride of that you can put `[A-Z]` at the leading of your regex :

```
[A-Z][^a-z]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5j34LcvHhtF15xsJ)

---

You can start here to learn more about regex http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
[A-Z][A-Z\d, ]*$
```

in `MULTILINE` mode to match your data.

This will match text that starts with an upper case letter and follows with an uppercase letter or digit or space or comma.

In Java use:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?m)[A-Z][A-Z\\d, ]*$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU2jE6/1)

Comment: that is not fully correct (as he just wants to exclude lower-case, we don't know could it include other symbols, like ":" or "-")

Comment: Without knowing requirement you can never say with surety "not fully correct". Let OP come up with more examples or better requirements then I can easily tweak the answer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following self-contained example/pattern to match the last string of characters starting with an uppercase word character and not containing any lowercase character:

```
String[] input = {
    "[POS Purchase]" + 
    System.getProperty("line.separator") + 
    "POS Signature Purchase International  SKYPE COMMUNICATIO, LUXEMBOURG, LUX",

    "ATM Cash Withdrawal. Surcharge: -3.0  BNEAIR INT DP LSL4 2, BNE AIRPORT, AUS"
};
//                            | starts with uppercase letter
//                            |      | uppercase letters or no letters
//                            |      |           | 0 or more times
//                            |      |           | | end of input
//                            |      |           | | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}[\\p{Lu}\\P{L}]*$");
for (String s: input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
SKYPE COMMUNICATIO, LUXEMBOURG, LUX
BNEAIR INT DP LSL4 2, BNE AIRPORT, AUS
```